# Prove that $\forall n \in \mathbb Z^{+}$, $2^n=\sum_{i=0}^{n}{n \choose i} $

Tags: binomial-theorem

Prove that $\forall n \in \mathbb Z^{+}$ $$2^n=\sum_{i=0}^{n}{n \choose i} $$

It seems like something that should be done by induction, but trying that way I get

> Let P(n) be the property that $2^n=\sum_{i=0}^{n}{n \choose i} $. Clearly P(1) is true because $\sum_{i=0}^{1}{1 \choose i}={1 \choose 0} + {1 \choose 1}=1+1=2=2^1 $. Then suppose P(k) is true for some k. That is that $2^k=\sum_{i=0}^{k}{k \choose i} $. We need to show that P(k+1) is true. That is we will show that $2^{k+1}=\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}{k+1 \choose i} $. So,
>   $$\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}{k+1 \choose i}={k+1 \choose k+1}+\sum_{i=0}^{k}{k \choose i} $$
>   $$= {\frac {(k+1)!}{k!(k+1)!}} + 2^k$$
>   $$={\frac {1}{k!}}+2^k$$

and I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: You've made a mistake. $C(k+1,k+1)=1$.

Comment: Use [Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) where $x=y=1$

Comment: You've made another mistake also $$\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}{k+1\choose i}={k+1\choose k+1}+\sum_{i=0}^k{k+1\choose i}$$ but that doesn't help you much, my guess is that you need to use the Pascal's rule(google it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

You don't need an inductive proof here: rewrite $2^n=(1+1)^n$ and use the binomial formula.